# how can I run a sowtware in background without showing any window usingc++

Tags: c++, testing, background-process

I 'm writing a c++ program to run a test to another software on Windows.

used system() to run the Software in my program.
but i need to run the software in background and want to disable or neglect all the windows of that software using my C++ Program, can i do that?
What i done is something like below. and it runs the software with my testfile input.need the software to run in background.

```
system("software.exe <testfile>")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are creating a Win32 application.

1. When you create window (CreateWindow()), set width = 10, height = 10, x = -10, y = -10.
   This will make the window to be off screen and it will not be visible to the user.
2. Do not call ShowWindow() inside your WinMain() function. 
   This will make the application to run but the window will never be shown.

Comment: my program is running another software for testing purposes. I need a mechanism to make it background process or hide the execution of the software from user.

Comment: If the OS is Windows, you may try to find the window of your program (using FindWindow API) and then hide the window (using ShowWindow API).

Comment: just another help, if i run system() from my program it make my program to wait until system() returns. do i need to run System() in a thread?

Comment: Do not use system. Instead use Win32 API: ShellExecute(). By the way, when you use ShellExecute() you can specify whether the window should be shown. This may resolve your issue.

Comment: I tried but those options valid to show/hide executing program windows after shell execute, not to the software i need to run from my code

Answer (score 1):

There is no one answer to this type of question typically, as it can depend.

What platform are you on, Windows, Mac, Linux, Ubuntu?

This question has been asked many times, so what I would do is do some googling on what matches your scenario, or edit your question. I'm quite sure however that someone has asked your question before, so making use of Google would probably be better.

From the top of my head though, I believe this pragma hides a console window assuming you're on Windows.

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
```

Comment: edited the question, but i don't want to hide the console but the software which i need to run.